# Can I use my Dell laptop screen to display HDMI input from a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, hdmi

I have a Dell Inspiron 14R (N4110) laptop and a Dell Inspiron  15R (N5110) laptop. Can I use either of them to display an input from a Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can use both your dell laptops to get raspberry pi's display screen instead of using hdmi cable follow these steps:

1. Give raspberry pi a static ip.In order to give static ip remove sd card and connect it to you computer. Go to file cmdline.txt and add your static ip say eg: "ip=192.168.1.5" don't use quotes.
2. Install putty for windows so that you can remotely log in into pi's command line
3. Log in into Pi using putty with a static ip you gave to Pi.
4. Install Xming software for getting display screen of pi on windows.
5. Start Xming from windows desktop.
6. Go to pi's command line and type lxsession.

For this to work both your laptop and Raspberry Pi must be connected in same network through Wi-Fi or Ethernet.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming the RaspberryPI has HDMI out, and both of your dells have HDMI out probably as well.  So you are stuck with a bunch of out connectors.  You may be able to network your RaspberryPI to one of your Dell's, and then use some sort of virtual display kind of like what you do if you have ever remote desktopped into your machine.